# Why am I unable to cout a dereferenced char pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, cout, dereference

When I try to run the following code, I don't receive any errors or warnings, but my terminal always crashes. Why is this and how do I fix it?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "colours.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    colour co(50,65,78);
    unsigned char *cp = co.getRGB();
    cout << *cp << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

colours.hpp

```
#ifndef COLOURS
#define COLOURS

class colour{
    public:
        colour(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b);
        unsigned char *getRGB();
    private:
        unsigned char red, green, blue;
};

#endif // COLOURS
```

colours.cpp

```
#include "colours.hpp"

colour::colour(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b) : red(r), green(g), blue(b) {
}

unsigned char *colour::getRGB(){
    unsigned char arr[3] = {red, green, blue};
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: in `getRGB` you return a pointer to a local variable which is destroyed when the function returns

Comment: @M.M Oh, arr[] wasn't in the scope, I see. But wouldn't my compiler at least bring up a warning, if not an error?

Comment: The language standard doesn't require a warning for this situation and it is up to the individual compiler to warn. Some do. [Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nNwIRK)

Comment: @M.M I see; I use CodeBlocks with GCC. Why wouldn't the standard have something for this, since I can't think of an instance where this would work?

Comment: It's not a problem if the caller never uses the returned value, and it would be unduly burdensome to require the compiler to analyze use of the function to see if this happened or not.  Generally speaking compilers avoid false-positive warnings in their default mode

Comment: @thepufferfish It is extremely difficult to write a compiler that detects all mistakes. It is also extremely difficult to craft rules for compilers that require detection of mistakes that are not unreasonably difficult to detect, but at the same time exclude those mistakes that are difficult to detect. In most cases it is simpler to let the compiler implementers decide what they can or cannot detect.

Comment: GCC also gives this warning so consider changing your warning flags or upgrading compiler version  (codeblocks comes with a crappy build of gcc by default). I see the warning with no extra flags even as far back as gcc 4.1, perhaps there is a warning but you are not looking in the right place?

Comment: By default gcc (like most modern compilers) is configured to NOT emit a lot of warnings, even when it can.    However, more warnings can be enabled with command line options, such as `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.   IDEs like Code::Blocks also, by default, run the compilers in their default settings, but can be configured (e.g. in Build options for a project) to enable compiler warnings.

Comment: @M.M, The version released this year comes with GCC 8 according to [this page](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries), so that's not bad comparatively at least.

Comment: @chris ah they have finally switched to mingw-w64 ... better late than never

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined an array locally on the stack in the following function:

```
unsigned char *colour::getRGB(){
    unsigned char arr[3] = {red, green, blue};
    return arr;
}
```

When the function returns, the stack is decremented and the array is no longer valid (as is the pointer to the array). Which is the reason your program crashes when you dereference the pointer.

To fix the problem, you could use an array for the colors, as you know the size at compile time.

```
std::array<unsigned char, 3> colour::getRGB(){
    std::array<unsigned char, 3> color = {red, green, blue};
    return color;
}
```

---

Another alternative is to allocate on the heap, instead of the stack,

```
unsigned char* colour::getRGB() {
    int size = sizeof(unsigned char) * 3;  // Get the size of 3 unsigned chars.
    unsigned char* color = (unsigned char*) malloc(size);
    color[0] = red;
    color[1] = green;
    color[2] = blue;

    return color;
}
```

This method comes with a few drawbacks. Firstly, you must remember to free the memory you've allocated when you're done with it.

```
colour a = colour(255, 0, 255);
unsigned char* rgb = a.getRGB();
// ---- DO STUFF ---
free(rgb);
```

Secondly, it is slow. Dynamically allocating memory this ways requires asking the operating system for more memory, which takes a bit of time.

Thirdly, since we already know that we want to have 3 unsigned chars, it's not necessary to dynamically allocate. Doing so removes the possibility for the compiler to do static analysis and optimizing the code.

Comment: Also a case for `std::tuple` here, as well as a `typedef` to make an RGB type.

Comment: I suppose an alternative route I could go is `void colour::getRGB(unsigned char *cp){ *cp = red; *(cp+1) = green; *(cp+2) = blue;}`. Your solution works really well for a return type, which is ideal.

Comment: @thepufferfish Yes, that's an alternative. However, since RGB is always 3 unsigned chars, I'd suggest you'd use C or C++ static type checking to avoid errors (and gain some speed). Use an array, tuple or create a struct to hold the values.

Comment: I must ask though, why are there the *less than* and *greater than* signs used as brackets? I can't think of ever seeing something like that before.

Comment: @thepufferfish It's a template argument. C++ introduced meta-programming and that new syntax. It allows you to dynamically modify the class definition at compile-time. The `std::array` class needs to know what type it should contain and how big it is, so we pass them in by the angle brackets to the class. This allow the compiler to do optimizations and type-checking at when building the program.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying. My compiler (which is apparently very outdated) doesn't seem to like std::array. It's saying `error: 'array' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type`. Aside from getting an update, I am curious for the sake of backwards compatibility, is there another way of returning an array? (*besides doing something like I did above with a pointer parameter and just changing the void return type to return the same pointer*)

Comment: @thepufferfish Yeah, you have to include the header `#include <array>` first. Depends what you mean with backwards compatibility. Array was introduced in C++11, so I don't think your interested in supporting older C++ versions than that. If you meant with C, you've already broken that because C doesn't have namespaces or classes.  But if you wanted to do this in C, you'd either use an inparameter (as you suggested), or create a struct with 3 unsigned chars that you return.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212126/discussion-between-thepufferfish-and-ted-klein-bergman).